# Blend2Java.py Shows Errors While Trying To Export

Tags: java, python, blender, vuforia

Trying to export to Vuforia java, I downloaded blend2java from (http://sourceforge.net/projects/blend2java/?source=typ_redirect)
So, I create a simple cube. Select Edit Mode and click 'a' to select all points. And then in text editor, I import the export.py file in. But when I run it, it gives me these errors:

```
File "xxx/xxx//xx/export.py" line 14, print "Gzip Module not supported"

Synytax Error: Missing Paranthesis in call to 'print'

locatoin <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one of the syntax changes between python2 and python3.

python 2.x you would use

```
print "some text"
```

in python 3.x you use

```
print("some text")
```

What this means is the script is written for blender versions older than 2.50. Since 2.50 blender has used python3.

The last update for blend2java was in 2004 so I can't say I expect it to be updated again.

I would suggest looking at what 3D file formats can easily be imported using java and use a matching [exporter from blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export). Some of the addons in that list are included in blender and just need to be enabled others will need to [be installed](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Add-Ons).